# What does a SQL SELECT command - that should return nothing - returns when I fill a DataTable (using a DataAdapter) with its answer?

Tags: c#, mysql, select

I have an application in C# that query on a MySQL database looking for a employee with a specific "code"/"number", but as the user type the code that will be used in the query it will might return nothing it the code doesn't exist.

So if the query returns nothing and I use a `dataAdapterObj.Fill(dataTableObj);` how can I discover if the query really returned nothing through the filled dataTableObj?

Comment: `if (dataTableObj.Rows.Count == 0) ...`

Comment: You can test with an query like "SELECT 1 FROM DAUL WHERE 1 = 0"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply test if there are rows in you table object :

```
dataTableObj.Rows.Count == 0
```

If this is `True` no rows where returned. Otherwise, you have some data.